# Choosing selected item for dropdown list in action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I have a page which allows users to change their privacy settings for:

- Their posted recipes
- Their profile
- Their posted lists

I am trying to form my code so that when the users load this page, the dropdown lists which they use to select their privacy settings display their current setting, so if they had their recipe privacy set to "Registered users", whenever they load the privacy settings page I want it to start off with "Registered users" selected.

Initially I create a list of `SelectListItem` instances called `PrivacySettings`

```
List<SelectListItem> PrivacySettings = new List<SelectListItem>();

            PrivacySettings.Add(
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text="Anybody",
                    Value = "0"
                });
            PrivacySettings.Add(
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = "Registered users",
                    Value = "1"
                });
            PrivacySettings.Add(
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = "Only me",
                    Value = "2"
                });
```

Then I create three separate `SelectList` instances. Here is the part where I am assigning the selected value for each of the lists to the first value which matches the user's saved setting.

```
SelectList RecipePrivacyList = new SelectList(
                PrivacySettings,
                "Value",
                "Text",
                PrivacySettings.First(x => x.Value == LoggedInUser.RecipePrivacy.ToString()));


            SelectList ProfilePrivacyList = new SelectList(
                PrivacySettings,
                "Value",
                "Text",
                PrivacySettings.First(x => x.Value == LoggedInUserProfile.Privacy.ToString()));

            SelectList ListPrivacyList = new SelectList(
                PrivacySettings,
                "Value",
                "Text",
                PrivacySettings.First(x => x.Value == LoggedInUser.ListPrivacy.ToString()));
```

Then I assign each of these to separate `ViewData` keys

```
ViewData["RecipePrivacy"] = RecipePrivacyList;
ViewData["ProfilePrivacy"] = ProfilePrivacyList;
ViewData["ListPrivacy"] = ListPrivacyList;
```

In my view I retrieve these and store them into variables

```
var ProfilePrivacy = (SelectList)ViewBag.ProfilePrivacy;
var RecipePrivacy = (SelectList)ViewBag.RecipePrivacy;
var ListPrivacy = (SelectList)ViewBag.ListPrivacy;
```

And finally I use the `Html.DropDownList()` helper method to create the lists using the aforementioned variables

```
@Html.DropDownList("profile-privacy", ProfilePrivacy, new { @class = "profile-privacy" })
```

When the view is loaded, the first value ("Anyone" or value 0) is selected regardless of the user's actual setting.

Comment: Maybe look at using `@DropDownListFor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set the selected item of the `SelectList` like that:

```
SelectList ListPrivacyList = new SelectList(
PrivacySettings,
"Value",
"Text",
PrivacySettings.First(x => x.Value == LoggedInUser.ListPrivacy.ToString()).Value);
```